# setTimeout ou setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu estou a usar um [`tooltip plugin` em jQuery](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy) para modificar atributos `title=""` de várias classes. Estava a correr tudo bem até que me apercebi de um problema - Eu estou a usar um botão que muda de classe conforme ele é clicado, e quando este botão muda de classe o tooltip deixa de funcionar.

É óbvio que eu experimentei adicionar a `class` do botão para a qual ela é alterada após ter sido clicada à mesma função do `tooltip` no JavaScript, mas isto não funcionou.

Então a minha solução para isto foi usar um `setInterval()` para correr esta função de `x` em `x` tempo para que o tooltip voltasse a funcionar de novo após a class deste botão ter sido modificada.

**Mas agora eu tenho 2 questões:**

- Quando nós utilizamos o `setInterval()` o pedido desta função está a ser enviado para o servidor cada vez que ela tenta correr de novo, ou ela está apenas a ser executada na própria **Janela do Navegador** em que o utilizador tem em aberto?
  (Isto é uma preocupação relacionada ao **Bandwidth** do servidor)
- Eu procurei e encontrei outra maneira de constantemente executar esta função utilizando `setTimeout` que dizem ser uma melhor maneira de abordar o mesmo.

**Então qual destas duas soluções será a melhor solução para abordar isto e qual é a diferença entre as duas?**

```
// setTimeout
(function loopingFunction() {
    $('.like-button').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'w'});
    setTimeout(loopingFunction, 500);
})();
```

```
// setInterval
setInterval(function(){
    $('.botao-gosto').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'w'});
}, 500);
```

Juntamente à minha pergunta vai aqui também um exemplo no JsFiddle caso possa ajudar: http://jsfiddle.net/jdbe0fL7/

Comment: `setTimeout` seria apenas um delay, já setInterval é uma repetição continua com delay.

Answer (score 3):

Esse plugin já tem opções para fazer isso. A sintaxe [segundo a documentação](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) é:

> $('#example-delay').tipsy({**delayIn**: 500, **delayOut**: 1000});

Um exemplo seria:

```
$('.like-button').tipsy({
    fade: true,
    gravity: 'w',
    delayIn: 500,    // pausa antes de abrir
    delayOut: 1000   // pausa antes de voltar a fechar
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/jdbe0fL7/2/

Das duas soluções que tinhas o `setInterval` era má ideia pois fica a correr o código indefenidamente sem necessidade.

**Nota / pedido de esclarecimento:**

Na tua pergunta referes *"ser enviado para o servidor"* e *"modificar atributos title de várias classes"*. O teu código não reflete isso daí a minha resposta a indicar a documentação. Se a resposta não fôr o que procuravas tenta ser mais específico. Regra geral usar o `setInterval` neste caso ou em caso de comunicação com o servidor é raramente a solução certa.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda @Sergio mas o problema aqui é que quando uma nova `class` é adicionada ao botão o plugin deixa de funcionar, ou seja o `title` volta a ser o title nativo e não o title costumizado do plugin. a não ser que actualize a página para que volte a ser o costumizado. Daí eu estar constantemente a correr o código várias vezes usando `setInterval`. só desta maneira é que consigo fazer com que o `tooltip` volte a funcionar novamente. Eu não consigo recriar este problema no jsfiddle pois no jsfiddle quando uma nova class é adicionada o botão continua a funcionar normalmente :\

Comment: @Chun o `setInterval` não pode ser a solução, isso é uma gambiarra má :) Explica melhor como estás a mudar a classe. Faz um jsFiddle com essa parte para eu perceber como estás a fazer isso e mudar o title.

Comment: Este é um script que não foi desenvolvido por mim, eu estou apenas a criar uma parte de um tema para esta plataforma por isso nem eu sei ao certo onde está e qual é o código que está a gerar esta `class` adicional para o tal botão no meio destes ficheiros todos. Mas eu consegui resolver o prolblema usando `.hover()` em vez do normal `$( document ).ready()` sugerido pelo plugin e agora está a funcionar correctamente! Obrigado por toda a ajuda amigo :)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema - verificando se o parent/wrapper `div` tem o mouse dentro dela utilizando `.hover()` em vez do `$( document ).ready()` que é [sugerido pelo plugin](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy#usage)

Por exemplo:

```
$(".parent-wrapper").hover(function() {
    $('.like-button').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'w'});
});
```